# Why are my ajax calls synchronous in Chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I've been trying to use some ajax in a chrome extension.

I have a content script which is supposed to add some html to an existing page.

I've tried `JQuery.get`, `JQuery.load` and `ng-include`.

And all of them show a warning in the console, telling me `synchronous XHR` are deprecated (aren't these assynchronous by nature???). And then the page shows this weird behavior, tells me that some `Pusher` is not defined, then refreshes the page and kills my inserted div.

What could be wrong??

Sample code - If I enable the first `var txt`, it works perfectly. If instead I enable the second `var txt` (commented), it fails.

```
 //this first line works perfectly
 var txt = '<div id="myNewDiv" ng-controller="myController">{{testing}}</div>'; 

//this shows the warning and a really weird behavior
//var txt = '<div id="myNewDiv" ng-controller="myController">{{testing}}<div ng-include="' + "'myhtml.html'" + '"></div></div>'; 


$('#a-certain-div-in-the-page').after(txt)

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.testing = 'Welcome!';
    });

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Comment: what's in your HTML  just mark-up or does it include Script references

Comment: Are you sure it's not the page itself that triggers the warning?

Comment: Hello, @CodeUniquely, yes, only markup. In fact I tried even with a plain text without any tags. The result is always the same. (For testing purposes, I was able to add the same HTML, typing its content in the code and using $('#...').append)

Comment: Hey, @Xan, yes. The warning only appears when I use the commented line for `var txt` in the code (which contains the ng-include) or when I Jquery load or get for the external html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is what happens:

1 - The extension domain is different from the page domain, so it tried to load things from the page's domain, not from the extension files. (And the resource was not found). The warning message is totally misleading in this case.

Solution: use `chrome.extention.getURL('myhtml.html')` to get the proper complete url. Or concatenate strings using your extension's ID to create a full path.

```
 var txt = '<div id="myNewDiv" ng-controller="myController">{{testing}}<div ng-include="' + "'" + chrome.extension.getURL('myhtml.html') + "'" + '"></div></div>';
```

2 - Even doing that, there is also a cross-domain request issue. The page only accepts requests from its own domain, unless you give it the right permissions. It's necessary to add in the `manifest.json` file the permission to this resource:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    ..... among many others ....

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "myhtml.html"
    ]

}
```